# WooCommerce: Can't use wc_get_products for custom REST API endpoints

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, query, hooks, rest-api, endpoints

I'm trying to create some custom REST API endpoints which get products with some special conditions, for example, one endpoint for featured products.
I tried to use the `wc_get_products` function like this:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'my_custom_featured_product_endpoint');

function my_custom_featured_product_endpoint() {
    register_rest_route('custom-endpoints/v1', '/products/featured', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_custom_featured_product_callback',
    ));
}

function my_custom_featured_product_callback() {
    $meta_query  = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
    $tax_query   = WC()->query->get_tax_query();
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
        'field'    => 'name',
        'terms'    => 'featured',
        'operator' => 'IN',
    );

    $args = array(
        'tax_query' => $tax_query,
        'meta_query' => $meta_query,
    );

    $result = wc_get_products($args);

    return rest_ensure_response($result);
}
```

The result is just some empty arrays. I can get those products with old fashion `get_posts` to replace `wc_get_products` but the output format doesn't have some properties like 'price', 'images' ...

So are there any alternatives for `wc_get_products` to use for custom REST API endpoints or are there any ways to make it work?

P/S: I tested the query by change the callback function like so:

```
function my_custom_featured_product_callback() {
    $result = wc_get_product(99);//Yes there is a product with ID 99

    return rest_ensure_response($result);
}
```

The result stays the same, just an empty array. So I think the issue must lie with the `wc_get_products` and `wc_get_product` functions. Maybe the `rest_api_init` is not the proper hook for those functions?

Comment: If you're getting an empty array and not an error, then the function is working fine. You're just not getting any posts that match your criteria. What are `$meta_query` and `$tax_query` ending up as anyway?

Comment: Actually the function is working fine in template files and return correct result with properly format. But when I use it with `rest_api_init` hook, the result is just some empty arrays.

Comment: I think your problem is your use of `WC()->query`. In the REST API WooCommerce won't have run a query.

Comment: As I edited the question, I changed the callback function to test if the problem is the use of query. Please check my question again.

Comment: Hang on, I'm not sure what you're doing with `rest_ensure_response()`. You should just be returning the `$result`. If you need the posts to match the normal format of returned posts, they need to be [prepared](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/253726/39152).

Comment: I tried both of your ways, still didn't get any result. But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

you missed something, when you get a product using wc_get_product it returns to you an abstract object, so if you need to get product do this

```
$product =  wc_get_product($product_id);
return $product->get_data();
```

also you can use all the other functionalities too, such as:

```
$product->get_status();
$product->get_gallery_image_ids();
...
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I had been trying to get product data for a long time. Was just missing `$product->get_data()`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar behavior where `$wc_get_product` always returned empty objects from a custom REST endpoint when I was checking the response with a console.log on the front end side.

It was because I was returning the PHP Object directly in the response, I solved the issue by converting the Product Object to an array with the help of the thread bellow :

[convert-php-object-to-associative-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)

After that it worked as expected, hopefully it'll be the same for you!

Answer (score 0):

Add `(array)` cast before `wc_get_products($args)` like this:

```
$result = (array) wc_get_products($args);
```

If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable names, with a few notable exceptions: integer properties are unaccessible; private variables have the class name prepended to the variable name; protected variables have a '*' prepended to the variable name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side. and you can access to product data by `*data` property.

Comment: `wc_get_products` is array itself ! (array of objects).