# wp_query json ouput

Tags: rest-api

I'm writng custom endpoints for my mobile app..

My output like [this](https://gist.github.com/sakarya/1b8a28cf9a0ea3d3134a)

Tried somethings, but getting null values for id, title and content.

```
function my_function($request) {

$data = array();
$id = (int) $request['id'];
$request = array();

if ( empty( $id ) ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'rest_post_invalid_id', __( 'Invalid term id.' ), array( 'status' => 404 ) );
}

$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'my_posttype_name',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy_name',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $id,
        )
    )
) );

print_r($query);

foreach ($query as $q) {
    $data['id'] = $q->posts[0]->ID;
    $data['title'] = $q->posts[0]->post_title;
    $data['content'] = $q->posts[0]->post_excerpt;

    $request[] = $data;
}

return new WP_REST_Response($request, 200);
}
```

How can I get that values?

Comment: I suggest you use `get_posts` instead of relying `WP_Query`, please take your time to visit @jgraup answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/212113 to figure out how to get json output.

Comment: yes. added $posts = $query->get_posts(); after wp_query, know it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running the query but you're immediately afterwards printing it out, you need to call the method [get_posts](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/query.php#L2477) or use something like a while statement with [have_posts](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/query.php#L760):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Just saw Jevuska response, credit goes to him for responding first but glad you got it working!